# 'An explicit value for the identity column can only be specified...' during Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2012, sql-merge

There are quite a few questions which cover this error, but I'm having the issue that:

A) I'm currently doing a Merge (with an Insert)

B) I'm not explicitly setting the identity column!

My stored procedure (table names and properties obfuscated):

### Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    [ID] BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Property] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_MyTable] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Value] ASC)
);
```

### Stored Procedure Definition

```
CREATE TYPE TempType as Table (
    [TempValue] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
    [TempProperty] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Name]
    @Source TempType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE [MyTable] as target
    USING (SELECT * FROM @Source) as source (TempValue, TempProperty)
    ON (target.Value = source.TempValue)
    WHEN MATCH THEN
        UPDATE SET Value = source.TempValue, Property = source.TempProperty
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ([Value], [Property])
        VALUES (source.TempValue, source.TempProperty)
        OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO [MyTable];

END
```

From what I can see, I'm not anywhere explicitly specifying the `IDENTITY` column. I am specifying a `UNIQUE`-ly constrained column though.

Lastly, contrary to what the error says, specifying `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` does nothing.

Edit: I should also specify, I'm getting this error while deploying from a `.dacpac` via C#.

Comment: `OUTPUT .... INTO [MyTable]` does seems like inserting into an identity column to me

Comment: It's inserting a new row and letting the table handle it though right? I'm able to insert into the table directly (not in a merge) elsewhere just fine. I should also clarify that I'm not sure what that output section is doing. That I copied from one of MSFTs examples and the `MERGE` doesn't seem to work without it. Is there a way to remove it or remove the insert?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need the `OUTPUT` at all

Comment: Ah, I think I see. I can just remove the table (or the whole OUTPUT) from the OUTPUT declaration and it works! I had been removing OUTPUT but not removing 'INTO MyTable' when testing before. If you want to add as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much!

Comment: It wasn't really an answer though, just an educated guess

Comment: It's an answer in that it highlighted the cause of the error, which was evading me. "The OUTPUT clause is inserting into your table and hitting the identity column, causing the issue."

Answer (score 0):

I would simply get rid of the MERGE statement (has lots of issues by design) and use a simple insert statement as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Name]
    @Source TempType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Value], [Property])
    SELECT s.TempValue, s.TempProperty 
    FROM @Source s
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [MyTable]  
                  WHERE Value = s.TempValue)

END
```

To read about issues with MERGE statement have a look at this article [`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Since you have added an update into your Merge statement, now I would also add an update statement and wrap the update and insert into one transaction but still I would not recommend using merge statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Name]
    @Source TempType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;


BEGIN TRANSACTION;

     UPDATE T
       SET T.[Property] = S.[Property]
     FROM [MyTable] T 
     INNER JOIN @Source s ON T.Value = s.TempValue



    INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Value], [Property])
    SELECT s.TempValue, s.TempProperty 
    FROM @Source s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM [MyTable]  
                      WHERE Value = s.TempValue)


COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to do `INSERT` and `UPDATE` as well?

Comment: @NateDiamond You aren't actually updating anything though. And you are inserting the rows when they do match your target table, so that's odd too

Comment: @NateDiamond As Lamak has already mentioned your Merge statement is only inserting when there is a matching row based on the criteria you have defined, there is no update at all in your merge statement, On a side note if you need and update, add a separate update statement to above solution and warp them both in ONE TRANSACTION, still I would stay away from Merge statement.

Comment: Whoops! Somehow the update section wasn't included in the post. Fixed! What's worse is I've already had my coffee :|

Comment: @NateDiamond have a look at my solution now, like I said before I would stay away from Merge statement.